# Heroku unable to reproduce H12 response time out error page

Tags: heroku, meteor

We had a H12 response timeout error page issue on our Heroku server.

When that happen, We estimate there was only about 20+ concurrent users.

We want to reproduce this in a stress test, and then update the server configuration to ensure it wont happen again.

But we couldn't reproduce the H12 application error page again regardless of how much stress we put on Heroku.

I used https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster to try to simulate 250 concurrent users.

The code is like this:

```
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');

var workerID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);

(async () => {
    // Create a cluster with 2 workers
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
        maxConcurrency: 5,
        puppeteerOptions: {
          headless: true, 
          args:['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
        }
    });

    // Define a task (in this case: screenshot of page)
    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
        await page.goto(url, {
          waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0
        });
        await page.waitForTimeout(10 * 1000) 
        const path = url.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '_') + '.png';
        await page.screenshot({ path });
        console.log(`${workerID}: Screenshot of ${url} saved: ${path}`);
    });

    // Add some pages to queue
    for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
      cluster.queue('https://server.com/page1');    
      cluster.queue('https://server.com/page2');
      cluster.queue('https://server.com/page3');  
    }

    // Shutdown after everything is done
    await cluster.idle();
    await cluster.close();
})();
```

I believe the code above simulates 5 concurrent users loading the pages. Then we created 50 dynos, effectively simulating 250 users.

But unfortunately, we didnt get the H12 error page at all. But we got a bunch of H27.

Any Heroku experts know why we didn't able to reproduce H12 in a stress test setup like this?

[image]

Comment: Do you use a dump of the actual database in the test? There is a difference between handling 5 documents for 250 concurrent users or handling 5000 documents for 250 users. Maybe this is where your leak is?

Comment: @Jankapunkt understand, I agree I simplified the situations. Let me test more thanks!